# Where does the unsafe variable been set

Tags: java, unsafe, atomicboolean

When studying the jdk source code (jdk 1.8.0_111), i found a piece of strange code as follow:

```
public class AtmicBoolean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4654671469794556979L;
    private static final Unsafe unsafe = ;
    private static final long valueOffset;
    private volatile int value;

    static {
        try {
            valueOffset = unsafe.objectFieldOffset(AtomicBoolean.class.getDeclaredField("value"));
        } catch (Exception localException) {
            throw new Error(localException);
        }
    }
  // .... other codes
}
```

Question:  where does the *unsafe* variable was set ?

Comment: paste that code in here, please. Remove the link to the image

Comment: It is being set in a static initialisation block.

Comment: `unsafe=;` shouldn't compile

Comment: from the `AtomicBoolean` class: `private static final Unsafe unsafe = Unsafe.getUnsafe();`

Comment: Considering there is a typo in the class name, I guess this is not the real code from the JDK. Edit: just saw the previous screenshot. Maybe the IDE displays it wrong or messed with the code. I just checked the sources of a few versions and they all use the fully qualified name of Serializable and have different field order (eg. value comes after the static initializer)

Comment: Just in case someone does not want to dig in the history: the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TEZP.png) from some IDE is really missing ```Unsafe.getUnsafe()```, which is actually present in the JDK.